# Bind ASP.NET ViewModel to List of Lists

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I have a StaffMembers Model

```
public class StaffMember
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string JobTitle {get; set;}
        public virtual ICollection<Payment> Payments { get; set; }
    }
```

and the payments Model:

```
  public class Payment
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; } = "Pending";
        public float Amount { get; set; }
        public int Month { get; set; }
    }
```

so every StaffMember has a total of 12 payments, one payment for each month.

Now I want to view and edit every StaffMember's payment for the current month in a view, so I wrote this ViewModel:

```
 public class MembersPaymentViewModel
    {
        public List<StaffMember> StaffMembers { get; set; }
    }
```

and in the cshtml file, I view all members and put the payments in a textbox as follows:

```
@foreach (var staffMember in staffMembers.Select((val, index) => new {index, val}))                                        
{
     <td>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m =>                                                             
        m.StaffMembers[staffMember.index].Payments.ToList()
        .FirstOrDefault(s => s.Month == currentMonth).Amount
     </td>
}
```

The problem is, when I post the form, the StaffMembers List in the ViewModel is always null,
but If I access the JobTitle property, which is not a collection:

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m =>                                                             
            m.StaffMembers[staffMember.index].JobTitle)
```

the ViewModel binds properly.
My question is, how can I bind the Payments property so the StaffMembers property in the ViewModel doesn't return null.

Comment: The code you posted is very unclear. You have to post the controller action where you create a model and a view

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add name attribute to inputs,so that the data will be binded to `Payments`:

```
@model MembersPaymentViewModel
@foreach (var staffMember in staffMembers.Select((val, index) => new {index, val}))                                        
{
     <td>
   <input value=@Model.StaffMembers[staffMember.index].Payments.ToList()..FirstOrDefault(s => s.Month == currentMonth).Amount name="StaffMembers[@staffMember.index].Payments[0].Amount" />
     </td>
}
```